# How can I create a twisted torus?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, pathfinder

I need to do the following shape in Illustrator, if can be done by Illustrator. I think it can be done by spiral, circle and pathfinder tools but I'm not sure. Please I need the details of how to do it, or if you have a tutorial that can help me about that.

[image: 4 edge twisted torus]

Comment: I think you could find more info if you name it a Moebius strip, or ribbon. It's almost the same concept. http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruban_de_M%C3%B6bius

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made this in about 3 minutes using the circle tool, direct selection tool and live paint. I don't know if there's a faster way, but this was pretty quick.

[image]

Basically, draw a circle and a smaller circle inside that circle. Draw a new circle that is the exact width between the left anchor point of the inner circle and the right anchor point of the outer circle:

[image]

duplicate this new circle into four. Move each circle so that their top/bottom anchor points or left/right anchor points are anchored to corresponding anchor points of the inner and outer circles, like so:

[image]

Use the *Direct selection tool* and remove the anchor points that creates the paths you don't want. Here I've removed three anchor points and need to remove one more, the one for the left circle:

[image]

After that you're done, and you have the basic structure to fill or do whatever you like with:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. Well, how can I color each spiral after I trim the circle?

Comment: Yea, you use the *Direct Selection Tool* (white arrow) and with that you can delete specific points of what makes up the shape. So, if you have a circle, select the right most anchor point and press delete you will get a half circle. Look at this short vid for an introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7CpHuHomUg

Comment: how can I color each spiral after I trim the circle?

Comment: @HTMLMan You use the selection tool, select the entire shape. Go *Object* -> *Live paint* -> *Make*. Then you use the *Live Paint Bucket* tool (K shortcut on Windows) to fill the areas of the spiral. To add additional effects, such as the glow in your example, I would personally use Photoshop (I don't know Illustrator THAT well) =)