# How to generate bent rays?

Tags: vector, inkscape, shapes

I'm struggling to draw a set of a certain number of curved lines springing off a point.

The picture below shows more or less what I'm trying to do (except the outer circle):

[image: Bent rays]

Is there an obvious way to obtain this in Inkscape?

Comment: Check out this similar question [How can I create a twisted torus?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16218/how-can-i-create-a-twisted-torus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see the Inkscape tag, when I posted my first answer.  My first answer was the quick, easy way I would have done it, admittedly not the best.  This is the more accurate way that I would create that shape (there may be a better one?).  This was done in Illustrator, but I would imagine that the same technique can be applied to Inkscape.

I first created a circle

[image: circle]

Then I deleted one of the 4 anchor points, giving me an arc

[image: arc]

I then duplicated and rotated the arc, in this case by 72<sup>o</sup>, to achieve a twisted star of lines

[image: rotating]

[image: star]